# No me funciona Mysql en phpMyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

En phpMyAdmin me sale el siguiente error :

> Cannot log in to the MySQL server . mysqli::real_connect():
> (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de
> destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión

Comment: ¿Está corriendo el servicio de MySQL? Asumo que usás XAMPP: revisalo ahí. Lee [ask].

Comment: mira tengo el siguiente problema y no se como solucionarlo. c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.36\bin\mysqld.exe me indica que no encuentra este archivo